How can I install or use custom font like Inter in Laravel Breeze React
Ive been trying to use Inter font for my laravel breeze react project but i still cant find any solution that work.
Ive tried manually move the ttf file in resources/fonts/ and then import it into app.css but its still doesnt work.
@font-face {
    font-family: "inter";
    src: url("/resources/fonts/inter.ttf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

html {
    font-family: "inter", sans-serif;
}

Ive tried to find the index.html file but there isn't any because its a laravel project. and in the app.jsx also doesnt work.
I would like to make all the font in my site using inter font

Does this answer your question?

Does this answer your question? How to add fonts to create-react-app based projects?
